# Show that $RU$ intersects $AB$ at the midpoint (of $AB$).

Tags: geometry

$PA, PB$ are tangents. $PU$ is a reflection of $PS$ over $PO$ where $O$ is the center of the circle. Show that $RU$ intersects $AB$ at the midpoint (of $AB$).

It looks so obvious. And I can see a lot of similar triangles. But I can't really solve it.

[image]

Please avoid solutions that use inversive/projective geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $TS$ and $RU$ meets on $AB$ because $P$ is the pole of the line $AB$.
On the other hand $TS$ and $RU$ meets on the simmetry axis $PO$ because they corresponds under the reflection.

Thus $TS\cap RU=AB\cap PO$ and $AB\cap PO$ is the mid point of $AB$ because $OP$ is axis of $AB$.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Let $UM$ intersect the circle again at $R'$.

Note that $\angle OAP = 90^\circ = \angle PBO$. So $APBO$ is cyclic.

Using power of the point twice we get 
$$UM \cdot MR' = AM \cdot MB = PM \cdot MO.$$

It follows that $UOR'P$ is cyclic. Since $OU=OR'$, the line $PO$ is the angle bisector of $UPR'$. This means that $PU$ and $PR'$ are symmetric wrt to $PO$, so $R'=R$. Done!